# ISR syntax with ARM-GCC

Tags: gcc, syntax, arm, isr

The demo code on the web for defining an ISR for ARM is generally this:

```
__irq void ISRFunc (void);
```

Using ARM-GCC, this gives syntax errors on compile, I've tried obvious variants like `_irq` but they all have the same problem. Some google references state that you don't need to specify the function as an ISR, i.e. `void ISRFunc(...)` will also work. However, I'm having trouble getting my programs to run, so it would help a lot if someone could confirm (a) is the type specifier `__irq` (or equivalent) required, and (b) what should it be to avoid compile errors.

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__isr` is [ARM C compiler specific](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0056d/ch05s05s01.html) keyword (and looks like it was [Keil specific too](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124968488.htm), but obsoleted), and will not compile via GCC.

As per [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html), following is the syntax for declaring ARM interrupt service routine:

```
void __attribute__((interrupt("IRQ"))) do_irq()
{
    //your irq service code goes here
}
```

Extra details:

In fact, you may use any of the following to inform compiler that your function is the interrupt handler.

```
void __attribute__((interrupt)) ...
void __attribute__((interrupt("FIQ"))) ...
void __attribute__((interrupt("IRQ"))) ...
```

The difference is both `"IRQ"` and `"FIQ"` should switch register contexts and save certain 
registers (`"FIQ"` stacks nothing), while plain `interrupt` is more a general "save 
what you use here and restore when exiting".

Comment: Thanks Andrejs. That's one more uncertainty I can tick off!  Cheers

Comment: You're welcome! Do not forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: I will as soon as I find out how to do it!

Comment: People on this website receive reputation by up-voted and accepted answers. [Here is detailed info on how this is done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/134824).